# ASP.net Identity framework or Simple membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, simplemembership, asp.net-identity

I am building **ASP.net MVC** 5 website which is having User login module as well.

Requirement is to store User custom information (ex: DOB, Email, Preferences, Security Question, Password & other information).

Whether I should use Simple Membership or **ASP.net** Identity framework or I should built a custom authentication module ?

*-- I did search over Internet but didn't find sufficient information*

Comment: There are also other alternatives, like [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) and [MvcAccount](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcAccount)

Comment: Max,  Can I use them in live Environment and how about maintainability(support)?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of this QA, "ASP.NET Identity vs Simple membership Pros and Cons?".  You can find my answer to this question there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207246/asp-net-identity-vs-simple-membership-pros-and-cons

Answer (score 2):

For new applications being built with MVC 5, you should use ASP.NET Identity which is the new membership system for web apps. For more information on the features you can read this article http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: Ya if you use Code First. No easy way to use when the approach is Model First.

Comment: Why do you say that @Dave ?

Comment: @nico - to be honest I don't remember since my comment was 3 years ago. We have since converted to Code First but are still using Simple Membership. Hopefully we will convert to Identity at some point.