# Authorization and authentication in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I am a complete beginner in ASP.NET and looking for a simple example that makes use of authentication and authorization. (Form authentication)

I have looked around and there are so many different ways that it's being done.

Like ASP.NET membership and ASP.NET login controls.And then there is another way Asp.net Identity

If anyone can provide a good starting point.

Comment: "good" is entirely subjective and specific to your exact requirements, scenario and operating constraints, none of which we know. Even then, why would an example someone linked to or wrote out here be any better than what you can find on google - as you pointed out, there are lots of examples out there. You need to find the design which suits your particular needs. If you're not sure which would be better, then study the features of each and think about your site's needs in more detail.

Comment: Hi you can try courses on Microsoft Virtual Academy or you can go to this link - https://www.asp.net/identity. i think you can start here from scratch and they have example projects too..- Im just assuming you might want to know about asp.net identity and how it works..

Comment: I need one that uses database first approach and form authentication

Comment: @DrewAguirre which is better using identity or membership?

Comment: personally, identity is better to learn than membership.  you can see this stack overflow q & a, it has a detailed comparison and explanation between identity and membership https://stackoverflow.com/a/21382483/7967972

Comment: When you're indeed doing MVC then "login controls" shouldn't come up. Get Core 2, try the standard templates. The one with individual user accounts should get you started, maybe even finished,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based entirely on the fact that you are new to ASP.NET

My recommendation would be to look at the ASP.NET Identity setup. You can easily set up users, manage their roles, and do most of the difficult work using Identity. There's still be some manual work involved but you'll get to learn the basics and in production it can still be quite a powerful tool. Most of the products I have created or used have all had an Identity backend for their user management. Once you've become quite advanced in ASP.NET and understand how it works, you'll be able to look at other options along with their benefits and downfalls over Identity. But until that time, stick to the Identity framework. Should you get stuck and need help, you'll find plenty of online support and a large community of people who understand it enough to help you solve your problems (which might not be the case with other frameworks).